# MDIParent Tiling children

Tags: .net, winforms, parent, mdi, mdiparent

Is there any way to tile all of the form children of an mdi parent easily? I'm looking for most of the functionality that windows offers, tile cascade. Anyone know of an easy way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try these...

```
// Tile all child forms horizontally.
this.LayoutMdi( MdiLayout.TileHorizontal );

// Tile all child forms vertically.
this.LayoutMdi( MdiLayout.TileVertical );

// Cascade all MDI child windows.
this.LayoutMdi( MdiLayout.Cascade );
```

Comment: You are the wind beneath my wings.

Comment: I had to put this.LayoutMdi into protected override void OnShown to get the layout working work http://stackoverflow.com/a/2836353/74585