# LayoutMdi fails in form's OnLoad event

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

Hello I have OnLoad eventhandler like this:

```
private void MainView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileVertical);
}
```

But nothing happens. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, doesn't work.  Probably because the child windows aren't visible yet.  It works fine in the Shown event:

```
    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
        var f2 = new Form2();
        f2.MdiParent = this;
        f2.Show();
        f2 = new Form2();
        f2.MdiParent = this;
        f2.Show();
        this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileVertical);
    }
```

Comment: This works. I had to put this.LayoutMdi into protected override void OnShown whereas previously I had put this.LayoutMdi into the Form constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Either that or in the .MdiChildActivate() event handler of the MDI parent form:

```
private void MDIParent_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.Cascade);
}
```